# connection with LDAP Server using java swing application

Tags: java, swing, ldap

I am trying to make a tool in swing for end user to use some specific web services..!! but got stucked in first phase..**User authentication** !! I want to authenticate the user with LDAP ..Please provide some efficient code snippet or Idea that i can authenticate my user for furthure processing. i have been working with swings only so still no idea of JNDI and LDAP. trying to get an idea about LDAP and JNDI ..but time is most important concern. plz give it a thought.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try Apache Shiro, an application security framework that can handle LDAP.